# How to pass variables to a best_in_place display_as custom method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, best-in-place

I am trying to pass variables to a best_in_place display_as custom method. Something like the code below:

```
<%= best_in_place @track, :forms_metadata,
    type: :date, 
    nil: 'Set Due Date',
    display_as: :this_forms_metadata(@track, form.id),
    path: update_forms_metadata_admin_track_path(@track, form_id: form.id) %>
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ')'
```

In tracks_controller.rb:

```
def this_forms_metadata(track, form_id)
  track.forms_metadata[form_id.to_s]["due_date"]
end
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong, or is this even possible?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you post the full error message and the parameters you're expecting in the `best_in_place` method?

Comment: That seems to be the only error message I'm getting. I added what the method looks like in the controller above. If that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass

```
this_forms_metadata(@track, form.id)
```

as a method not a symbol.
Secondly you cannot use controller method in your view, you should move

```
this_forms_metadata(@track, form.id)
```

to helper file and then use it as a method not a symbol.
Here is what you need to write in your view

```
<%= best_in_place @track, :forms_metadata,
 type: :date, 
 nil: 'Set Due Date',
 display_as: this_forms_metadata(@track, form.id),
 path: update_forms_metadata_admin_track_path(@track, form_id: form.id) %>
```

move your method 'this_forms_metadata' to helper file